# Compare two xml files and display difference

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to compare two xml files and display the differences, if found.

At the moment I am using [XML Diff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa302294.aspx) to find the difference.

The method use

```
 private bool CheckDifferences(string originalFile, string newFile, ref string difference)
    {
       var diff = new XmlDiff
       {
           IgnoreComments = true,
           IgnorePI = true,
           IgnoreWhitespace = true,
           Algorithm = XmlDiffAlgorithm.Precise
       };

        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        var originalReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(originalFile));
        var modifiedReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(newFile));
        var status = diff.Compare(originalReader, modifiedReader, writer);

        difference = sw.ToString();
        writer.Close();
        originalReader.Close();
        modifiedReader.Close();

        return status;
    }
```

But `difference` will contains only the change, not what exactly changed.

For example what I am trying to achieve is

**xml1** - Original File

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk11">
      <author>AuthorName1</author>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

**xml2** - New File

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk11">
      <author>AuthorName2</author>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

***So I would like to display that author is changed to AuthorName2 etc...***

The xml file structure is unknown, but both files will have the same structure.

Also looked at the [XNode.DeepEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it also return whether is there any difference or not. But not what the difference is.

Any help is appreciate

Comment: Please give an example of what difference contains, and what you would like it to contain instead.

Comment: @Polyfun: As I mentioned in question, for the sample xml i provided, I would like to display author is changed to ->AuthorName2

Comment: I assume they will have an id.   Why not just read the XML and compare.

Comment: Notepad++, for exemple has a pluggin that allows you to compare two files. Why developping something when so many tools can already do that?

Comment: @Fjodr: This is not just to compare two files. One is coming from a web service and other one from different source. This is for end user to validate and check the differences. Otherwise there are so many online tools !!!

Comment: You could unserialize your files inside a class that implements IComparable You would have to use xmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Compare` method only returns `true` or `false` but, by looking at the documentation, the differences are written, as a XML document, to the diffgram writer (which is intended for XML Patch). So you can always interpret that document and show the changes how you want.

Comment: Yes, it does create a xml but the content looks like `<xd:change match=\"1\">AuthorName2</xd:change>`

Comment: That's not the whole thing, I believe. But you're right, that format is meant for XML Patch and not easy to understand. Still, it contains the needed information to show what you want, that is, "author is changed to AuthorName2".

Comment: It will have loads of information, but the issue is by looking at the result how to identify `AuthorName2` is related to node `<author>`